# java regex sometimes fails to match

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to understand working of regex matching in java and have a doubt in the followeing code snippet

When i run it :http://ideone.com/2vIK77

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {


         String a = "Basic";
         String b = "Bas*";

         boolean matches = Pattern.matches(b, a); 
         System.out.println("1) "+matches);


        String text2    =
        "This is the text to be searched " +
        "for occurrences of the pattern.";

        String pattern2 = ".*is.*";

        boolean matches2 = Pattern.matches(pattern2, text2);

        System.out.println("matches2 = " + matches2);


    }
}
```

it says 
false on first and true on second .

```
1) false
matches2 = true
```

I am not able to understand why am i getting false in first case .. I expect it to be true  . 
Can someone please suggest me something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `*` means "zero or more of the previous character", which was "s".

The docs for [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) say:

> Attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
>
> **Returns:**
>   true if, and only if, the entire input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

So, "Bas*" only describes the first part of your input text, not the whole text.  If you change the pattern to `"Bas.*"` (the dot character means "any character") then it will match because it will be saying:

```
"B" then "a" then "s" then any number of anything (.*)
```

Answer (score 5):

The first pattern: `"Bas*"`, will match any string that starts with `"Ba"` and then consists of zero or more `s` characters (`"Ba"`, `"Bas"`, `"Bass"`, etc.). This fails to match `"Basic"` because "Basic" does not conform to that pattern.

The second pattern, `".*is.*"`, uses the *wild card* character `.`, which means "match any character". It will match any text that has the string `"is"` anywhere in it, preceded and/or followed by zero or more other characters.

The [docs for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has a detailed description of all the special elements that can appear in a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in `b` variable, what you want is `Bas.*` instead of `Bas*`